# Modal issues for WordPress search form

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm building a WordPress site with a modal window for entering search terms. On submit, the modal window is supposed to close and the search results are returned on the search results page.

I've tried WordPress' native search functionality (4.7), as well as Search Filter Pro (2.2). Both search forms work correctly and reroute if they are used in the main content area, NOT in a modal.

`example.com/search/?_sf_s=pigs` (I cannot show the dev site without client permission)

But when using the modal window, upon submit, the page does not redirect, but the URL query changes to:
`example.com/?_sf_search%5B0%5D=pigs&_sf_submit=Search`

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for the modal, but I've also tried another jQuery plugin (leanModal.js). Both of them reproduce the problem in the exact same way.

Is there a fundamental problem with submitting a form in a modal window? Is the closing of the modal window triggering a callback that somehow prevents the form _POST from firing? Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thx,
Michael

Comment: Most likely you have javascript preventing the default action on your anchor tags within the modal, which would indeed prevent the form from POSTing.